# Parsing a coworker's "About Me"

Tags: translation, slang

One of my coworkers has the following as their About Me on slack:

> 小老板不说话装糕手 多捞哦

As someone who recently joined this company, I'm embarrassed to admit I don't know what it means - I can translate it, but I don't think I have the cultural(?) context to understand what it's saying. Specifically, I'm not sure what 糕手 should translate to (cake hand?). How should I make sense of this phrase?

Comment: 糕手 sounds like “高手”.

Comment: "多捞哦", sounds like Cantonese, anybody knows what it means?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's a play on 糕 & 高. If so, then the co-workers are giving what is called a playful backhanded compliment, with no malice involved, I hope, because 糕, (pastry), in full is 蛋糕, and 蛋, could also morph to 笨蛋, "a fool", which via this convoluted route we get 糕手, or, "butter fingers", (butter being a main ingredient in pastry) I could of course be completely wrong.

Comment: @r13 it is a quote from a famous Chines league of legend streamer(大司马). 多捞哦 means the played very bad. Like "trolling" used by English streamer of the game.

Comment: @Archeosudoerus So, strictly speaking, both the 糕手 and the 多捞哦 are slangs created after the internet gaming, correct?

Comment: @r13 Yes. It is definitely the Internet that got them popular

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to a popular league of legend streamer. 糕手 is 高手 (pro).